# Converting Scala array of Int to Java array of Integer

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

How to convert Scala `Array[Int]` to Java `Integer[]`? It seems that the default is to convert int to `int[]` and that's not a proper argument for method defined as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] merge(T[] xs)
```

Compiling fails with the following error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Int]
 required: Array[? with Object]
Note: Int >: ? with Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: ? with Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
      val res = SimpleSort.merge(xs)

                             ^
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe with:

```
val javaArray: Array[java.lang.Integer] = scalaArray map java.lang.Integer.valueOf
```

AFAIK, it is not a good practice in java to manipulate array of objects, you should use Lists instead. BTW, your `merge` method will have trouble instantiating the array of `T`.

Comment: This converts to an scala `Array[Integer]` not a java `Integer[]`

Comment: Scala's Array[Integer] and Java's Integer[] should be exactly the same.

Comment: I just tested my solution: it compiles.

Comment: Just checked, you're right. BTW, I also found there's a method `Int.box` on scala's `Int` which boxex an `Int` to an `Integer`, so you can rewrite as `scalaArray.map(Int.box)`

Comment: Or you could take advantage of the implicit conversion from `Int` to `Integer` with `scalaArray map (x => x: Integer)`